# How not to execute it block when the above it block has failed

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

Consider there is a describe block and two it blocks inside the describe block.

```
describe(""){
   it(""){
   }       //if this block fails script should not execute next block
   it(""){
   } 
}
```

If first it block fails script should not execute next it block. how do you achieve this in protractor. Please help.

Comment: Can't you wrap the code in `try...catch` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Example:*

```
describe('first test', function () {
    it('Second test', function (done) { /* some code */});
    it('Third test', function (done) { /* some code */});

    it('employee test', function (done) {
        //It should be an object
        var employee = getEmployee(); 

        expect(employee).not.toBeNull();
        expect(employee.name).not.toBeNull(); // if employee == null will not stop here and throw an exception later
        expect(employee.name).toBe(‘tarun’);

        done();
    });

it('employee test', function (done) {  });

});
```

I would suggest You to wrap the second and third expect in try/catch, one for both or one each, and manually deal with the caught errors, then fail with Jasmine's fail().

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the blocks within `try-catch`. Then you can use some Boolean values to check if the first it block executed successfully and execute the second it block.

```
describe(""){
    try{
        var firstSuccess = false;
        it(""){
            //do whatever...
            firstSuccess = true;  //set firstSuccess to true at end of it block
        }       //if this block fails script should not execute next block
        if(firstSuccess){   //execute second it block only after first it executes successfully
            it(""){
            }
        }
    }catch(err){
        //handle error here
    }  
}
```